# access shortcode atts in template part

Tags: shortcode, buddypress

How can I access the $atts in a BuddyPress template?

```
function test_shortcode_callback( $atts, $content='' ) {

    ob_start();

    shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'foo' => 'this is foo',
            'bar' => 'default bar',
        ), $atts, 'test_shortcode' );

    bp_get_template_part('my-template');

    return ob_get_clean();

}
add_shortcode( 'test_shortcode', 'test_shortcode_callback' );
```

Unlike `load_template`, `bp_get_template_part` does not have an `$args` parameter.
In the template, `has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'test_shortcode' );` returns true .

But how can the $atts be accessed? I could store them in post meta, but I hope there is a simpler approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use a global and set the value to `$atts`.